# Extensionless REST WCF service returns http 405 for PUT method

Tags: wcf, rest, iis-6, http-status-code-405, svc

I have a WCF REST service running locally under IIS6 written in VS2008 (3.5).

The asp.net ISAPI mapping for the svc file is configured to accept all verbs
I have enabled wildcard script mapping to allow extensionless URI's to work with the service via url rewrite.

So running a PUT to the rest service with the .svc file specified works OK.
Doing the same with the svc omitted returns a 405.

i.e

http://thehost/therestmethod = 405
http://thehost/theservice.svc/therestmethod = 200

All the url written versions work with PUT being the only exception! When attempting the PUT on the extensionless version I hit the url rewrite ok but errors after so I know the rewrite succeeded.

I've tried using WCF tracing but this isn't logging the error. It seems it's not getting that far?!?!

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd547388):

HTTP Verbs: While most firewalls and web clients allow for the HTTP GET and POST verbs, some of them do not support PUT, DELETE, and other verbs. To enable the invocation of such unsupported verbs, a common practice is to use the X-HTTP-Method-Override HTTP header on a POST request to specify the method you wish to call. The XHttpMethodOverride sample describes how to implement this functionality.

I imagine something isn't quite aligned in the IIS url re-write / allowed verb checking code.
Hope this helps.

Comment: As there is no firewall involved this would eliminate that plus the fact that including the svc file works ok